# How to sort by file name the same way Windows Explorer does?

Tags: powershell

This is the famous problem of "ASCIIbetical" order versus "Natural" order as applied to powershell. To be able to sort in powershell the same way as explorer does, you can use [this wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/csnsort.aspx) over StrCmpLogicalW API, that actually performs the natural sorting for Windows Explorer. This will require some plumbing though.

However, [this article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order.html) suggests that there is a three liner implementation of the sort in python. One would hope that Get-ChildItem cmdlet or at least File System Provider can have built-in natural sorting option. Unfortunately, they do not.

So here is the question, what is simplest implementation of this in Powershell? By simple I mean the least amount of code to write, and possibly no third-party/external scripts/components. Ideally I want a *short* Powershell function that would do the sorting for me.

Comment: Thanks to the interesting question, I have just tried to use a regular expression match evaluator in PowerShell. And it actually works! I should think of other applications, then.

Comment: FYI, the three-liner won't work like Windows Explorer. `1` will be sorted before `+1`, which is not the case in Explorer.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

TL;DR

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
```

Here is some very short code (just the `$ToNatural` script block) that does the trick with a regular expression and a match evaluator in order to pad the numbers with spaces. Then we sort the input with padded numbers as usual and actually get natural order as a result.

```
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }

'----- test 1 ASCIIbetical order'
Get-Content list.txt | Sort-Object

'----- test 2 input with padded numbers'
Get-Content list.txt | %{ . $ToNatural }

'----- test 3 Natural order: sorted with padded numbers'
Get-Content list.txt | Sort-Object $ToNatural
```

Output:

```
----- test 1 ASCIIbetical order
1.txt
10.txt
3.txt
a10b1.txt
a1b1.txt
a2b1.txt
a2b11.txt
a2b2.txt
b1.txt
b10.txt
b2.txt
----- test 2 input with padded numbers
                   1.txt
                  10.txt
                   3.txt
a                  10b                   1.txt
a                   1b                   1.txt
a                   2b                   1.txt
a                   2b                  11.txt
a                   2b                   2.txt
b                   1.txt
b                  10.txt
b                   2.txt
----- test 3 Natural order: sorted with padded numbers
1.txt
3.txt
10.txt
a1b1.txt
a2b1.txt
a2b2.txt
a2b11.txt
a10b1.txt
b1.txt
b2.txt
b10.txt
```

And finally we use this one-liner to sort files by names in natural order:

```
Get-ChildItem | Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
```

Output:

```
    Directory: C:\TEMP\_110325_063356

Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                  
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                  
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 1.txt                                                                                                                 
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 3.txt                                                                                                                 
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 10.txt                                                                                                                
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 a1b1.txt                                                                                                              
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 a2b1.txt                                                                                                              
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 a2b2.txt                                                                                                              
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 a2b11.txt                                                                                                             
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 a10b1.txt                                                                                                             
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 b1.txt                                                                                                                
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 b2.txt                                                                                                                
-a---        2011-03-25     06:34          8 b10.txt                                                                                                               
-a---        2011-03-25     04:54         99 list.txt                                                                                                              
-a---        2011-03-25     06:05        346 sort-natural.ps1                                                                                                      
-a---        2011-03-25     06:35         96 test.ps1
```

Comment: You can save that $ToNatural scriptblock in your profile, then it will be available to you whenever you want it.

Comment: I tried this and found it does not work when you have something like:
1.1 Testfile.txt
1.2 Testfile.txt
1.10 Testfile.txt
While it does display in this order in an explorer window.

Comment: It works for me, I have just tried. Are you expecting sort by "floating point numbers"? Then a different script is needed.

Comment: That one-liner is gold. You should put it at the top of your answer as a TL;DR.

Comment: It isn't perfect. Consider: `0fe68296`, `01b7f045`  and `1a2a5773`. In Explorer, when sorting by name, they are in the order above. Yet, the code in the answer makes it sort into: `0fe68296`, `1a2a5773`, `01b7f045`.

Comment: I made gist to show that issue:  https://gist.github.com/AgainPsychoX/4e6aabc8e8832a2afde1386d038eda31

Answer (score 10):

Allow me to copy and paste my answer from another question.

[Powershell Sort-Object Name with numbers doesn't properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23818825/powershell-sort-object-name-with-numbers-doesnt-properly/48332768#48332768)

Windows explorer is using a legacy API from shlwapi.dll which called `StrCmpLogicalW`, that's the reason seeing different sorting results.

I don't want to pad zeros, so wrote a script.

https://github.com/LarrysGIT/Powershell-Natural-sort

Since I am not a C# expert, pull requests are appreciated if it's not tidy.

Find following PowerShell script, it uses the same API.

```
function Sort-Naturally
{
    PARAM(
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Array,
        [switch]$Descending
    )

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace NaturalSort {
    public static class NaturalSort
    {
        [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
        public static System.Collections.ArrayList Sort(System.Collections.ArrayList foo)
        {
            foo.Sort(new NaturalStringComparer());
            return foo;
        }
    }
    public class NaturalStringComparer : IComparer
    {
        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            return NaturalSort.StrCmpLogicalW(x.ToString(), y.ToString());
        }
    }
}
'@
    $Array.Sort((New-Object NaturalSort.NaturalStringComparer))
    if($Descending)
    {
        $Array.Reverse()
    }
    return $Array
}
```

Find test results below.

```
PS> # Natural sort
PS> . .\NaturalSort.ps1
PS> Sort-Naturally -Array @('2', '1', '11')
1
2
11
PS> # If regular sort is being used
PS> @('2', '1', '11') | Sort-Object
1
11
2

PS> # Not good
PS> $t = ls .\testfiles\*.txt
PS> $t | Sort-Object
1.txt
10.txt
2.txt

PS> # Good
PS> Sort-Naturally -Array $t
1.txt
2.txt
10.txt
```

Comment: Can you give advantages/disadvantages of your answer as compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: Not the OP but...
Pros:
+ Battle Tested Implementation
+ Guaranteed to behave exactly the way windows explorer does.
+ Doesn't use padding so should handle arbitrarily large numbers. (20+)
Cons:
- Depends on windows DLL so Linux versions of Powershell probably can't use this.
- Always possible they could remove DLL one day from Windows.
Neutral:
* Couldn't find any appreciable speed difference between this and regex version.

Comment: Actually, looking at it again, the C# solution does seem faster on multiple iterations.

Comment: This was the only answer in here that actually sorted the same way File Explorer does. Thank you.

Comment: @WillB3 a few people state this but with no support / details. Can you give an example that sorts correctly by this but not by the accepted answer?

Comment: @Larry Song Unfortunately, I was not able to get this to run.
Sort-Naturally : The term 'Sort-Naturally' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet...
Any thoughts on why and how do I use the descending option?

Answer (score 8):

I prefer @Larry Song's answer because it sorts exactly the way Windows Explorer does. I tried to simplify it a little to make it less intrusive.

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
public static class NaturalSort
{
    [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
    public static string[] Sort(string[] array)
    {
        System.Array.Sort(array, (psz1, psz2) => StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2));
        return array;
    }
}
"@
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$array = ('1.jpg', '10.jpg', '2.jpg')
[NaturalSort]::Sort($array)
```

which outputs:

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
10.jpg
```

Comment: Several people voiced concern that the accepted answer does NOT sort the same way Explorer does. Do you happen to have an example?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh, yes I do. You can try `1.txt` vs `1_.txt`.

Comment: @Elderry I was not able to get Larry Song's solution to work.  I need to reverse the sort.  Can you add that as an option and show an example of using it, please?

Comment: You can always [reverse an array](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/powertip-use-powershell-to-reverse-array/#:~:text=How%20can%20I%20use%20Windows%20PowerShell%20to%20reverse,%3D%201%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%20%24b%20%3D%20%24a%20%7C%20sort%20-Descending) after you get the result. @dashboard

Answer (score 3):

Translation from python to PowerShell works pretty well:

```
function sort-dir {
    param($dir)
    $toarray = {
        @($_.BaseName -split '(\d+)' | ?{$_} |
        % { if ([int]::TryParse($_,[ref]$null)) { [int]$_ } else { $_ } })
    }
    gci $dir | sort -Property $toarray
}

#try it
mkdir $env:TEMP\mytestsodir
1..10 + 100..105 | % { '' | Set-Content $env:TEMP\mytestsodir\$_.txt }
sort-dir $env:TEMP\mytestsodir
Remove-Item $env:TEMP\mytestsodir -Recurse
```

You can do it even better when you use [Proxy function approach](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/03/01/proxy-functions-spice-up-your-powershell-core-cmdlets.aspx). You add `-natur` parameter to `Sort-Object` and you have pretty beautiful solution.

**Update**: First I was quite surprised that PowerShell handles comparing arrays in this way. After I tried to create test files `("a0", "a100", "a2") + 1..10 + 100..105 | % { '' | Set-Content $env:TEMP\mytestsodir\$_.txt }`, it turned out that it doesn't work. So, I think there is no elegant solution like, because PowerShell is static under the covers, whereas python is dynamic.