# Finding a file that has highest number in the filename using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Sorry guys..I am new to powershell. Would be great if someone help with the following scenario:

I have couple of files in a folder c:\test

```
sample.x.x.1
sample.x.x.2
sample.x.x.3
sample.x.x.4
sample.x.x.5
```

I want to find the name of the file which has the highest number in its name in the given folder. In the above example, 5 is the highest number and the script should return the output filename as sample.x.x.5

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorting file names with numbers is quite a problem, as there are two ways. The first one sets them to alphabetical order. That is, `0, 1, 11, 111, 2,...` The second one uses natural order. That is, `0, 1, 2, 11, 111...`. This is surprisingly tricky and about every third programmer is confused with this.

There's a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/503046) already, which I'll refer like so,

```
# Create files 1..5
for($i=1;$i -le 5; ++$i) { set-content sample.x.x.$i -Value $null } 

# Tricksy! Create file .10 to confuse asciibetic/natural sorting
set-content sample.x.x.10 -Value $null

ls # Let's see the files

    Directory: C:\temp\test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.1
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.10
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.2
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.3
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.4
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.5

# Define helper as per linked answer
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+$', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20,"0") }) }

# Sort with helper and check the output is natural result
gci | sort $ToNatural -Descending | select -First 1

Directory: C:\temp\test

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       2015-09-28     10:29              0 sample.x.x.10
```

Comment: Maybe worth noting that the asciibetic/numerical sorting issue arise from the *type* of the input object. If you know what substring you want to sort on, it's as easy as casting it to a numerical type: `sort { $_.Substring($_.LastIndexOf('.')+1) -as [int] }`

Answer (score 1):

Alphabetical sorting.

```
PS C:\Users\Gebb> @("sample.x.x.1", "sample.x.x.5", "sample.x.x.11") | sort
sample.x.x.1
sample.x.x.11
sample.x.x.5
```

Numerical sorting.

```
PS C:\Users\Gebb> @("sample.x.x.1", "sample.x.x.5", "sample.x.x.11") |
 sort -Property @{Expression={[Int32]($_ -split '\.' | select -Last 1)}}
sample.x.x.1
sample.x.x.5
sample.x.x.11
```

Largest number.

```
PS C:\Users\Gebb> @("sample.x.x.1", "sample.x.x.5", "sample.x.x.11") |
 sort -Property @{Expression={[Int32]($_ -split '\.' | select -Last 1)}} |
 select -Last 1
sample.x.x.11
```