# Sort Directory name using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have list of directories. Directories are named as numbers. How to sort the directory name in numeric order by power shell.

```
Name
-----
1
12
2
```

Comment: `sort {[int]$_.Name}`

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sort order is based on the *type* of the property being used for comparison.

Since the `Name` property of your directories are of type `[string]`, alphabetical sorting takes place, which ranks `10` before `9` (because the first character `1` precedes the character `9` in alphabetical order).

To sort the numbers by numeric value, use a scriptblock (as [shown in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664892/sort-directory-name-using-powershell#comment55103191_33664892)) or a calculated expression to cast the value to a numeric type:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Sort-Object -Property {$_.Name -as [int]}
```

Using `-as`, rather than a cast will prevent exceptions for objects where the `Name` property cannot be converted to `[int]`. The `-as` type operator is introduced in PowerShell version 3.0, so for earlier versions, use a regular cast:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Sort-Object -Property {[int]$_.Name}
```