# Powershell string sorting with expression based "columns"

Tags: powershell, sorting

Let's say I have a collection of strings like this, in no particular order:

```
"Filename (Text) (Comment)"
"Filename (Word) (1)"
"Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)"
"Filename (Text) (2)"
"Filename (Picture)"
"Filename (Misc)"
"Filename (Misc) (1)"
"Filename (Picture) (1)"
"Filename (Audio)"
"Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)"
```

I want to sort them like this:

```
"Filename (Text) (2)"
"Filename (Word) (1)"
"Filename (Text) (Comment)"
"Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)"
"Filename (Audio)"
"Filename (Picture) (1)"
"Filename (Picture)"
"Filename (Misc) (1)"
"Filename (Misc)"
"Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)"
```

In other words, I want to sort in this order: (Bad) to the bottom (Text/Word, Audio, Picture) on top of the (Bad)s and then sort on (2, 1, [blank]).

Note that I want Text and Word clumped together and then sorted on the number in parenthesis, and I don't care about anything that doesn't match those, so I don't care about (Comment).

Currently I'm getting this:

```
"Filename (Word) (1)"
"Filename (Text) (2)"
"Filename (Text) (Comment)"
"Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)"
"Filename (Audio)"
"Filename (Picture) (1)"
"Filename (Picture)"
"Filename (Misc) (1)"
"Filename (Misc)"
"Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)"
```

So I'm very close to getting what I want.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$badExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$documentExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$soundExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$imageExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$numberExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] } }

"Filename (Text) (Comment)", "Filename (Word) (1)", "Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)", `
    "Filename (Text) (2)", "Filename (Picture)", "Filename (Misc)", "Filename (Misc) (1)", `
    "Filename (Picture) (1)", "Filename (Audio)", "Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)" | Sort-Object `
@{Expression = $badExpression; Descending = $false}, `
@{Expression = $documentExpression; Descending = $true}, `
@{Expression = $soundExpression; Descending = $true}, `
@{Expression = $imageExpression; Descending = $true}, `
@{Expression = $numberExpression; Descending = $true}
```

I'm definitely misunderstanding how exactly my expressions are being applied to the sort. I have a hunch that maybe I have to do a sequence of Sort-Objects, but I can't really figure out what.

Just to draw the focus: The issue I have is that (Word) and (Text) are supposed to be sorted as if they were the same.

Edit: Okay I think I got the behavior I want now with this, a subtle change, see the -replace I added.

```
$badExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$documentExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'} }
$soundExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$imageExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] } }
$numberExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] } }

"Filename (Text) (Comment)", "Filename (Word) (1)", "Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)", `
    "Filename (Text) (2)", "Filename (Picture)", "Filename (Misc)", "Filename (Misc) (1)", `
    "Filename (Picture) (1)", "Filename (Audio)", "Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)" | Sort-Object `
@{Expression = $badExpression; Descending = $false}, `
@{Expression = $documentExpression; Descending = $true}, `
@{Expression = $soundExpression; Descending = $true}, `
@{Expression = $imageExpression; Descending = $true}, `
@{Expression = $numberExpression; Descending = $true}
```

So for internet points: What is my script doing (besides working), I'd like to understand it a little bit better. :) I understand what's happening loosely, but I'd like a better grasp of it.

Answer (score 1):

Its not straight forward. But I would prefer to first sort it to **Natural** first.

```
Get-Content C:\folder\String.txt | Sort-Object $ToNatural
```

Then at least you will directly get O/p like this (sorted with Audio,Misc,Pics,Texts):

```
"Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)"
"Filename (Audio)"
"Filename (Misc) (1)"
"Filename (Misc)"
"Filename (Picture) (1)"
"Filename (Picture)"
"Filename (Text) (2)"
"Filename (Text) (Comment)"
"Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)"
"Filename (Word) (1)"
```

After that you can use some regex to match according to your need. Let me know if this approach helps you.

Comment: Just stumbled over this answer, you missed to define the variable [$ToNatural](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411) like this `$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20,"0") }) }` I have it defined in my profile too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Six years late, and I got nerd-sniped by the *Related* sidebar, instead of doing *real work*...

```
("Filename (Text) (Comment)", "Filename (Word) (1)",                                 
 "Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)", "Filename (Text) (2)",                                                    
 "Filename (Picture)", "AAAAname (Misc)",                                                               
 "Filename (Misc) (1)", "Filename (Picture) (1)",                                                       
 "Filename (Audio)", "Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)") `                                                
| Sort-Object -Property `                                                                               
    @{Descending=$true; Expression={ switch -Regex ($_) { # reverse-sort by a numerical code     
        '\(bad\)'         { -2; break }    # push (bad) to the bottom (lowest code val)                   
        '\((text|word)\)' { 80; break }    # (text) or (word) come first (highest code val)               
        '\(audio\)'       { 60; break }                                                                 
        '\(picture\)'     { 40; break }                                                                 
        '\(misc\)'        { 20; break }                                                                 
        default           { -1 }           # unknowns are penultimate (second-lowest code val)
     }}},                                                                                               
    @{Descending=$true; Expression={ switch -Regex ($_) { #...then reverse-sort by the first (num)   
        '\(([0-9]+)\)'    { [Int32]($Matches[1]) }        # find any run of digits and convert to integer
        default           { -1 }                          # assume no negative (nums)                       
    }}}
```

> ```
> Filename (Text) (2)           
> Filename (Word) (1)           
> Filename (Text) (Comment)     
> Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)
> Filename (Audio)              
> Filename (Picture) (1)        
> Filename (Picture)            
> Filename (Misc) (1)           
> Filename (Misc)               
> Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)
> ```

The above assumes you are interested in the existence of `(Bad)` over anything else, then the *first* instance of one of your named `(Class)` values, then the *first* `(number)`.  Multiple classes/multiple numbers are non-deterministic.

You also didn't indicate if you wanted to sort on the actual `Filename` text itself so, in the above, it is also non-deterministic.  If you *did* want to sort the `Filename` text as well, try...

```
("Filename (Text) (Comment)", "Filename (Word) (1)",                                 
 "Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)", "Filename (Text) (2)",                                                    
 "Filename (Picture)", "AAAAname (Misc)",                                                               
 "Filename (Misc) (1)", "Filename (Picture) (1)",                                                       
 "Filename (Audio)", "Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)") `                                                
| Sort-Object -Property `                                                                               
    @{Expression={                                                                                      
        ($_ -split '\(')[0]                # first, sort by everything up to the first (                
     }},                                                                                                
    @{Descending=$true; Expression={ switch -Regex ($_) { #...then reverse-sort by a numerical code     
        '\(bad\)'         { -2; break }    # push (bad) to the bottom (lowest code val)                   
        '\((text|word)\)' { 80; break }    # (text) or (word) come first (highest code val)               
        '\(audio\)'       { 60; break }                                                                 
        '\(picture\)'     { 40; break }                                                                 
        '\(misc\)'        { 20; break }                                                                 
        default           { -1 }           # unknowns are penultimate (second-lowest code val)            
     }}},                                                                                               
    @{Descending=$true; Expression={ switch -Regex ($_) { #...finally reverse-sort by the first (num)   
        '\(([0-9]+)\)'    { [Int32]($Matches[1]) }        # find any run of digits and convert to integer
        default           { -1 }                          # assume no negative (nums)                       
    }}}
```

> ```
> AAAAname (Misc)               
> Filename (Text) (2)           
> Filename (Word) (1)           
> Filename (Text) (Comment)     
> Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)
> Filename (Audio)              
> Filename (Picture) (1)        
> Filename (Picture)            
> Filename (Misc) (1)           
> Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)
> ```

---

> So for internet points: What is my script doing...
>
> ```
> $badExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] } }
> $documentExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'} }
> $soundExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] } }
> $imageExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] } }
> $numberExpression = { if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] } }
>
> "Filename (Text) (Comment)", "Filename (Word) (1)", "Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)", `
>     "Filename (Text) (2)", "Filename (Picture)", "Filename (Misc)", "Filename (Misc) (1)", `
>     "Filename (Picture) (1)", "Filename (Audio)", "Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)" | Sort-Object `
> @{Expression = $badExpression; Descending = $false}, `
> @{Expression = $documentExpression; Descending = $true}, `
> @{Expression = $soundExpression; Descending = $true}, `
> @{Expression = $imageExpression; Descending = $true}, `
> @{Expression = $numberExpression; Descending = $true}
> ```

Your `$expression` variables are each storing a script block which would return a specific word, *if* that word is found in the current pipeline item; e.g. the script in `$badExpression` returns `Bad` if the pipeline item (`$_`) contains '(Bad)', and returns nothing if it does not.  *Nothing* comes before `Bad` in any .

Your `Sort-Object` sorts the list on each of those expressions, in turn.  For each of your strings, this extracts the following:

```
$_                                                                         : Filename (Text) (Comment)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  : DocumentDocument
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :

$_                                                                         : Filename (Word) (1)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  : DocumentDocument
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : 1

$_                                                                         : Filename (Word) (1) (Bad)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : Bad
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  : DocumentDocument
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : 1

$_                                                                         : Filename (Text) (2)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  : DocumentDocument
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : 2

$_                                                                         : Filename (Picture)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  :
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            : Picture
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :

$_                                                                         : Filename (Misc)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  :
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :

$_                                                                         : Filename (Misc) (1)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  :
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : 1

$_                                                                         : Filename (Picture) (1)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  :
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              :
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            : Picture
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : 1

$_                                                                         : Filename (Audio)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  :
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              : Audio
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :

$_                                                                         : Filename (Audio) (Comment) (1)
 if ($_ -match '\((Bad)\)') { $matches[1] }                                :
 if ($_ -match '\((Text|Word)\)') { $matches[1] -replace ".*",'Document'}  :
 if ($_ -match '\((Audio)\)') { $matches[1] }                              : Audio
 if ($_ -match '\((Picture)\)') { $matches[1] }                            :
 if ($_ -match '\((2|1)\)') { $matches[1] }                                : 1
```

The `$expression` scripts are somewhat circuitous, in that it doesn't strictly matter what they return as long as it is binary (exists vs not-exists).  You could easily replace most of them with just the `{ $_ -match '\(...\) }'` part, if you wanted to, and sort on the resulting booleans.

The reason your first approach sorts `(Text)` before `(Word)` is because that is what you are asking it to sort, when it gets to that expression.  `$documentExpression` returns the term that was matched `$matches[1]`, and `\((Text|Word)\)` means that term could be `Text` or `Word`.  As such your sort is done on across *three* possible terms (`Word`, `Text` or *nothing*) instead of across two (exists, not-exists).

Your second version of `$documentExpression` takes whatever term was in `$Matches[1]`, discards it and replaces it with `DocumentDocument`, which resolves it back to the binary exists/not-exists condition.

(That it replaces it with `DocumentDocument` instead of just `Document` is peculiar.  My best guess is that there is a race condition between the `-match` and the `-replace` – both operators would usually populate `$Matches`, and it is probably choking on reading the value and writing at the same time.)

`$numberExpression` is the only expression that is legitimately expected to have more than one value to sort over, because you have asked for `1` or `2`, so sorting on `$Matches[1]` there makes some sense.