# How do I sort a string by its numerical value in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sorting

I'm trying to create a script that will list the servers I need to list along with the latency returned from each server, I need the list to be in ascending or descending order based on ping.

What I've come up with so far has given basically what I want, but if the ping returned is above 100 on one server, the other values are considered to be higher if they start with a value higher than 1.

I understand that I need the ping value returned as an integer, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to accomplish that with out removing the server name.

Anyway, here's what I've come up with so far

```
function TestNetwork {
    $global:array = @("<ServerName>:<ipaddress>"; "<ServerName>:<ipaddress>"; "<ServerName>:<ipaddress>")

    foreach ($str in $global:array) {
        $avg = 0
        $server = $($str -split ":")[0]
        $PingServer = Test-Connection -Count 3 $server
        $avg = ($PingServer | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Average)
        $calc = [System.Math]::Round($avg.Average)
        $output = "{000} | " -f $($calc) + $server
        $Output
    }
}
TestNetwork | Sort numerical -Descending `
```

and here are the results I get

```
75 | Server    
73 | Server  
110 | Server
```

Comment: You should output the results with a CustomObject and not format the numbers as strings.

Comment: Use a different string format operator to right align the numbers `$output = "{0,3} | " -f $($calc) + $server`

Comment: Or let a [RegEx do the padding left on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411) when sorting `TestNetwork | Sort-Object -desending { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to address your problem.

You could [format](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) the number in a way that aligns integer sort order and string sort order as [LotPings suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032109/how-do-i-sort-a-string-by-its-numerical-value-in-powershell#comment87081424_50032109):

```
'{0,3} | {1}' -f $calc, $server
```

You could also extract the number from the string, convert it back to an integer, and use that as the sorting property:

```
... | Sort-Object {[int]($_ -replace '(\d+).*', '$1')} -Descending
```

However, I wouldn't advise either approach. The PoSh way of doing things is to work with objects as [Olaf pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50032109/how-do-i-sort-a-string-by-its-numerical-value-in-powershell#comment87080444_50032109), so wrap your data in custom objects and convert them to strings only if you have a reason to do so (e.g. to create text output):

```
foreach ($str in $global:array) {
    ...
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
        'ComputerName' = $server
        'ResponseTime' = $calc
    })
}
```

That way you can "naturally" sort your data:

```
TestNetwork | Sort ResponseTime -Descending | ForEach-Object {
    '{0,3} | {1}' -f $_.ResponseTime, $_.ComputerName
}
```

or

```
TestNetwork | Sort ResponseTime -Descending | Export-Csv 'output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response, this works perfectly! The reason I wasn't using custom objects is because I needed the output to be a single line that I could grab and convert with a switch. Thanks again, this was a HUGE help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to the way you are doing things that will give output that can be sorted and formatted more easily:

```
function Test-Network
{
    $array = ("<ServerName>","<ipaddress>"), ("<ServerName>","<ipaddress>"), ("<ServerName>","<ipaddress>")

    $array | ForEach-Object {                            
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            AvgResponse = [Math]::Round((Test-Connection -Count 3 $_[0] | Measure-Object ResponseTime -Average).Average)
            Server = $_[0]
        }
    }
}

Test-Network | 
    Sort-Object AvgResponse -Descending
```

Output will look like this:

```
AvgResponse Server  
----------- ------  
        363 server1
         12 server2
          2 server3
```

The nice thing about outputting custom objects like this rather than strings is that you can then use further PowerShell techniques on the output, such as sorting, grouping, etc.

Note a couple of other points:

- Unless you intend to use your array outside the function, there is no need to declare it as 'global'
- Unless you really need the names in the format `"<ServerName>:<ipaddress>"`, consider storing them differently. I've used an array of arrays, which makes it easier to work with in this case as you avoid having to split a string each time.
- You should name your functions according to the PowerShell Verb-Noun naming standard, so `Test-Network`, rather than `TestNetwork`.

Answer (score 1):

Cast string to integer

```
TestNetwork | Sort {[int]($_.numerical)} -Descending
```