# Powershell sort string elements delimited by semicolons

Tags: powershell, sorting

I  have a string wit a following content, delimited by semicolons:

```
echo $content

BCS3;BCS2;DigitalIO;GAElectricDrive;J1939;SKF15;UBloxGNSS;VIMS
```

Perhaps my question is noob, but I cannot figure out, how to sort this values alphabetically, e.g. I want to receive following output(first and second elements are not in alphabetical order):

```
BCS2;BCS3;DigitalIO;GAElectricDrive;J1939;SKF15;UBloxGNSS;VIMS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Content = "BCS3;BCS2;DigitalIO;GAElectricDrive;J1939;SKF15;UBloxGNSS;VIMS"

$Content = ($Content -split ';'|Sort) -Join ';'

$content
BCS2;BCS3;DigitalIO;GAElectricDrive;J1939;SKF15;UBloxGNSS;VIMS
```

But the sorting is alphabetical, words containing numbers with differing places are sorted 1,10,100,2,20,200.

To avoid this you can use [$ToNatural](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411)

```
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }
$Content = "1;10;100;2;20;200"
$Content = ($Content -split ';'|Sort $ToNatural) -Join ';'
$content
1;2;10;20;100;200
```

Comment: lol - that's great. I got my inspiration from [this](https://gist.github.com/markwragg/e2a9dc05f3464103d6998298fb575d4e). Perhaps you did to?

Comment: I think the link `HE` refers to is from [Ronan Kuzmin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411) and the/one origin. I have `$ToNatural` in my profile.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks! I only need alphabetical, but your answer more than enough!