# PDF Printing Script

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell-2.0

I need to print many documents and I don't want to go to each selecting it and printing all. These documents have revisions and are all in the same folder. I want to print the latest revision for these documents. The format for these documents is

```
630-0-110
9A-0-9 
44-0-190
44-0-191
```

Of these four pdf files, `44-0-191` is a later revision than `44-0-190` so I would like to print `630-0-110`, `9A-0-9`, `44-0-191`

I need to print numbers starting with `6-0-`(revision no.) up to `699A-0-`(revision no.) and some of them have A,B,C in the beginning as well.

Is there a way to create a shell to print these automatically? Or do I have to manually ctrl+click all of them to print them?

If I can create a shell how do I Do it?

Comment: bash, cmd and powershell are 3 different things.  I would say, if you are on Windows, bash is sort of out of the question.

Comment: Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Please paste the code you are trying to make work into the question. If you do not have any code and need to hire a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent.

Comment: I'm on windows. What's best to use

Comment: A search machine. Or you hire a programmer. StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service, neither does it take over your research. So you have to try to implement your task on your own, and when stuck, come back here, providing a [mcve]! Read also the [tour]!

Comment: I'm not asking for code. I am asking if this can be done and if so what do I need to do?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. I would use powershell, but a more recent version than 2.0. Get 5.1 from Microsoft or 6 from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Your task requires several steps

- List documents, use a RegEx to split name from revision,
- group the documents by name,
- per group sort by revision numerically,
- get only the highest rev. (last one)

---

- select a printer / or use a defined one / default standard printer

---

- feed your preferred pdf app with the list of documents to print ([Print a pdf with Adobe Reader](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e4bf56b2-b5d2-4bc0-8d43-cc43ceeebf30/printing-pdfs-to-a-specific-printer?forum=winserverpowershell) )

Since your revision numbers have a diverging count of places you need to sort numerical,
this is realized with [$ToNatural](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411)

To test the sorting I used an extended sample (revisions to print are marked **)

```
44-0-19.pdf      
44-0-190.pdf
44-0-191.pdf    **
44-0-2.pdf
630-0-110.pdf   **
630-0-90.pdf
9A-0-10.pdf     **
9A-0-9.pdf
```

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\09\SO_51246286.ps1
#Requires -Version 3

## To sort numbers with a different places count use:
## $ToNatural from Roman Kuzmin source https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20,"0") }) }

Push-Location "X:\start\folder"

$PDFsToPrint = (Get-ChildItem *.pdf -File |
  Where-Object BaseName -match '^([0-9]+[A-C]?-\d+)-(\d+)$'|
    Group-Object {$Matches[1]} |
      Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object $ToNatural | Select-Object -Last 1
      } ).FullName
# $PDFsToPrint

Pop-Location

$Printer = Get-Printer | Select-Object Name,Drivername,PortName |
   Out-GridView -Title "Select the printer for output" -OutputMode Single

#Adobe SDK: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/Acrobat_SDK_developer_faq.pdf
$Acrobat = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe'

ForEach($Pdf in $PDFsToPrint) {
    $ArgList=' /S /T "{0}" "{1}" "{2}" {3}' -f `
        $Pdf,
        $Printer.Name,
        $Printer.DriverName,
        $Printer.PortName

    Start-Process $Acrobat -ArgumentList $ArgList
    #Start-Sleep -Seconds 60  #optional delay    
}
```