# ffmpeg converting m4s to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg-dash

I'm working on DASH, trying to optimize QoE for the end user.

I had a video and encoded it using ffmpeg into different bitrates and everything is fine, and the video is playable using dash.

What I want is to combine the received segments from the users into one m4s and convert that m4s to mp4.

I tried a lot of ways in ffmpeg, but it always give me this error:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x9a9e500] could not find corresponding track id 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x9a9e500] could not find corresponding trex
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x9a9e500] error reading header
test2.m4s: Invalid data found when processing input
```

segment_1.m4s is there.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: You are missing the initialization fragment at the start of the file.

Comment: @szatmary I encoded the videos my self and 38 segments are all what I got. they are all combined into that m4s file where should be the initialization segment ?

Answer (score 7):

## This works

Combine the m4s segments together into one file, making sure the file order is correct. E.g.

```
cat video-0.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-1.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-2.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-3.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-4.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-5.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-6.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-7.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-8.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-9.m4s >> all.m4s
cat video-10.m4s >> all.m4s
```

And then do all your conversions at once.

```
ffmpeg -i all.m4s -c copy video.mp4
```

## This doesn't

I get the same issue (`could not find corresponding trex`) trying the streaming method.

I had all the files I wanted in a `all.txt` file, which contained

```
file 'video-0.m4s'
file 'video-1.m4s'
file 'video-2.m4s'
file 'video-3.m4s'
file 'video-4.m4s'
file 'video-5.m4s'
file 'video-6.m4s'
file 'video-7.m4s'
file 'video-8.m4s'
file 'video-9.m4s'
file 'video-10.m4s'
```

And I tried `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i all.txt -c copy video.mp4`, resulting in the same issue.

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fde2d0c520] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fde2d0c520] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fde2d0c520] could not find corresponding track id 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fde2d0c520] could not find corresponding trex
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x55fde2d0c520] error reading header
[concat @ 0x55fde2cff900] Impossible to open 'rifle-1.m4s'
[concat @ 0x55fde2cff900] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none, 1280x720): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, concat, from 'all.txt':
[... omitted ...]
all.txt: Input/output error
```

Comment: Yes same issue all files in same place but still gives error

Comment: How about init segment? what needs to do for init segment?

Comment: @user8783065 you concatenate the m4s files after the init segment, I do `for x in *.dash *.m4s; do cat $x >> output.mp4; done` where the init segment is a `.dash` file

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the other answers but I found a case that is slightly different.
Concatenating the m4s files I got the same `could not find corresponding trex` error.

I got this m3u8 playlist:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:5
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MAP:URI="/mypath/something.mp4"
#EXTINF:3.000,
something001.m4s
#EXTINF:3.000,
something002.m4s
#EXTINF:3.000,
something003.m4s
#EXTINF:3.000,
something004.m4s
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

And I had to concatenate all of them starting with the mp4 file. The mp4 file was only 1.1kB and had no video but only the headers, I guess.

After concatenating the files it may be played by some softwares but it's not very compatible so then you have to let ffmpeg fix it for you.

This worked for me:

```
ffmpeg -i allgluedtogetherinorder.mp4 -vcodec copy -strict -2 video_out.mp4
```

**UPDATE:**
If your ffmpeg had the m3u support activated at compile time then you can convert the playlist to mp4 and it will resolve everything and give you a perfect video.
You may need to edit the paths to the files in the m3u files so it can find them.
Then:

```
ffmpeg -i playlist.m3u -vcodec copy -strict -2 video_out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2):

First file to be concatenated the initialization segment, followed by other segment file.

windows powershell:

Sort and list the Video files

```
 Get-ChildItem -name v1*.m4s| Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } > list.txt
```

Audio files

```
 Get-ChildItem -name a1*.m4s| Sort-Object { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) } > list.txt
```

( refer : [How to sort by file name the same way Windows Explorer does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does?noredirect=1&lq=1))

```
 type *init*.mp4 list.txt > Filename.mp4
```

Linux :

```
 ls -1v v1*.m4s > list.txt
 cat *init*.mp4 list.txt > Filename.mp4
```

Comment: Please check if all your data is present init.mp4 - sps,pps etc.