# How to get the greatest increment number of folder name in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have folders that were named incrementally, for example `Folder 01 TAG` `Folder 02 TAG` `Folder 03 TAG` and so on. However in the same path, there will be folders that have different name too if that's relevant. Any idea to make powershell return a simple largest increment folder name? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like the following as starting point...

```
$numbers = $null
$numbers += (dir "Folder * TAG" | select Name).Name | % { 
   if ($_ -match "(.*)(\d)(.*)") { 
      $Matches[2] 
   } 
}
$maxNumber = [int]($numbers | sort-object -Descending)[0]
$maxNumber++
$foldername = "Folder $maxNumber TAG"
$foldername
```

Comment: To also have 2 digits for the (not asked for) **next** free foldername use `$foldername = "Folder {0:00} TAG" -f $maxNumber` (+1)

Comment: This works great, however it matches only one digit number (it stopped working for number greater than `09`), I changed the regex to `(.*)(\d{2,2})(.*)` instead. And would you mind explain why `$maxNumber++` is necessary?

Comment: $maxNumber++ raises the number by one, as I meant you want to have the next free foldername. So in the case you actually want the last used foldername you can omit the $maxNumber++.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 3):

Since the numbers have a fixed width, sorting on NTFS file systems isn't neccessary.

In case of unsorted file systems and numbers with different places,
 I'd use [$ToNatural from Ronan Kuzmin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/6811411) it extends every number to 20 places.

```
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }

Get-ChildItem "Folder [0-9]* TAG" -Dir|Sort-Object $ToNatural|Select-Object -Expand Name -Last 1
```

Answer (score 2):

here's yet another way to do it ... [*grin*]

```
# fake reading in a list of directories
#    in real life, use Get-Content -Directory
$DirList = @(
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Folder 02 TAG'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Folder 03 TAG'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Dir Some Word'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Dir Other Word'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Folder 66 TAG'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Folder 05 TAG'
[System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'Folder 01 TAG'
)

$NextNumber = [int](($DirList |
    Where-Object {$_ -match ' \d{2} '} |
    Sort-Object |
    Select-Object -Last 1).Name -replace '[^0-9]') + 1

$NextDirName = 'Folder {0:D2} TAG' -f $NextNumber

$NextNumber
$NextDirName
```

output ...

```
67
Folder 67 TAG
```

what it does ...

- filters out any dir name that has no digits in it
- sorts the items [defaults to full name]
- selects the last one
- grabs the `.Name` of that object
- replaces any non digit with nothing
- coerces the `[string]` to an `[int]`
- adds one to it
- uses the `-f` string format operator to make a new Dir name with the new highest number