# How can I get the latest version of my versioning tagging?

Tags: git, powershell

Given the following:

```
PS C:\Users\jhau\Downloads\Trainee\I\GIT\Main\TEST000.git> git tag     
V2.1  
V2.25         
V5.0.0.0   
V5.0.141.0  
V5.0.600.0  
V5.0.640.0
```

How can I write a command to obtain the latest version tag, e.g. `V5.0.640.0`. I've tried this but it does not give the desired output

```
PS C:\Users\jhau\Downloads\Trainee\I\GIT\Main\TEST000.git> git describe --tags --abbrev=0  
V5.0.0.0
```

Comment: So you want the latest v5 tag?

Comment: yes i want to get the V5.0.640.0 the latest

Comment: [This should pretty much do it for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55048704/542251)

Comment: Has `V5.0.0.0` been committed AFTER `V5.0.640.0`?

Comment: yup V5.0.0.0 commited after V5.0.640.0

Comment: How do you define "latest" then? ;-)

Comment: Are you looking for : `git tag --sort="v:refname"` ? described in [git help tag (--sort option)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#Documentation/git-tag.txt---sortltkeygt)

Comment: Untested but, this should work (*if the latest tag is always last*): `(Git Tag)[-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a custom definition of "latest" (`V5.0.640.0` being latest, while `V5.0.0.0` has been committed after `V5.0.640.0`), you are basically looking for a way to sort version numbers.

Be aware that git tags can be any strings, not just version numbers of a certain format. As you use a certain format, you can parse those version numbers, convert them to a version number type, sort them and get the largest value. This is how you can do it in PowerShell:

```
git tag | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'tag'     = $_
        'version' = [System.Version]($_ -ireplace 'v', '')
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property 'version' | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty 'tag'
```