# Getting latest Go lang version using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Go lang source code can be found at the repository below, it does not have release tag as `latest`

```sh
https://github.com/golang/go/tags/go[0-9\.]
```

Or at:

```sh
https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go[0-9\.]
```

While the binary can be downloaded from one of the below links:

```bsh
https://dl.google.com/go/go[0-9\.]+\.windows-amd64.msi
// Or
https://golang.org/dl/go[0-9\.]+\.windows-amd64.msi
```

I want to write a PowerShell code, that extracted the latest release number from one of the first two links above then downloading it using one of the last two links.

I'm able to download and install it using the below script, I just unable to fetch latest release programmatically:

```bsh
# Install the current Go release
param(
    [string]$w='',
    [string]$v='1.15'
)

# installer file
$file = 'go' + $v + '.windows-amd64.msi'

# set defaults
$workDir = 'Documents\go'
$url = 'https://golang.org/dl/' + $file
$dest = Join-Path $Home "Downloads"
$dest = Join-Path $dest $file

# if $w wasn't passed; use the default
if ($w -eq "") {
    $gopath = Join-Path $Home $workDir
} else {
    $gopath = $w
}

# Setup the Go workspace; if it doesn't exist.
If (!(Test-Path $gopath)) {
    New-Item -path $gopath -type directory
}

# Create GOPATH and set PATH to use $GOPATH\bin
$gopathbin = Join-Path $gopath "bin"
#$gopathbin = ';' + $gopathbin

# set the $GOPATH
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "GOPATH", $gopath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User )

# see the $GOBIN
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "GOBIN", $gopathbin, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User )

Write-Output "downloading $url"
# Download the msi file at the defined destination
Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $dest

Write-Output "$url downloaded as $dest"
Write-Output "installing $v..."
# Run the msi
Start-Process $dest

Write-Output "done"
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Building on the accepted answer, here is the full code of my `goinstaller.ps1` file, which can be used for installing GO lang at Win10, regardless fresh install, or upgrade:

```bsh
Write-Output " Welcome to GO lang portable installation script"
Write-Output " Written by: Hasan A Yousef, Aug 2020"
Write-Output " =============================================="
Write-Output " GO lang SDK will be installed at C:\go\bin"
Write-Output " GO lang (GOPATH) will be set as 'Documents\GoWorkPlace'"
Write-Output ""

#Here is the installation function, at the bottom of the file are the check for update process
function InstallGo {
    param (
        $latest_version,
        $workDir
    )
        # The download location of the latest version zip file
        $file = 'go' + $latest_version + '.windows-amd64.zip'

        # set defaults
        $path = 'C:\go'
        $url = 'https://golang.org/dl/' + $file
        $dest = [io.path]::combine($Home, 'Downloads', $file)

        If(test-path $path)
        {
            $pathAll = $path + "*"
            Write-Output " Removing the currently installed Go from $path"
            Remove-Item $pathAll -recurse
        } else {
           # New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $path
           Write-Output " Creating the directory required for GO installation: $path"
           mkdir $path
        }
        # Download the zip file at the defined destination
        Write-Output " Downloading $url"
        Invoke-WebRequest $url -OutFile $dest
        Write-Output " $url downloaded as $dest"

        # Unzip the file
        Write-Output " Extracting $file to $path"
        Expand-Archive -Force -Path $dest -DestinationPath $path\..
        Write-Output " Extraction completed, Adding GO SDK to path"
        # Add GO to the Path (if not exisiting)
        $addPath = 'C:\go\bin'
        # Iterate through all the existing paths to check if the new path is already included with or without a '\' on the end:
        $env = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH",1)
        $regexAddPath = [regex]::Escape($addPath)
        $arrPath = $env -split ';' | Where-Object {$_ -notMatch "^$regexAddPath\\?"}
        $env = ($arrPath + $addPath) -join ';'
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $env, "USER")
        Write-Output " $addPath had been added to path."

        Write-Output " GO SDK is ready in the path, setting up Environment Variables"
        #Setting up variables
        # set the $GOBIN, GOBIN is a variable that defines where your Go SDK is located
        $gobin = Join-Path $path "bin"
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "GOBIN", $gobin, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
        # set the $GOPATH; GOPATH is a variable that defines the root of your workspace
        $gopath = Join-Path $Home $workDir
        [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "GOPATH", $gopath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::User)
        # Setup the Go workspace; if it doesn't exist.
        If (!(Test-Path $workDir)) {
            New-Item -path $workDir -type directory
            Write-Output " Go work space had been created: $gopath"
        } else {
            Write-Output " Go work space already exist: $gopath"
        }
        Write-Output " =============================================="
        Write-Output " GO is ready, Below you'll see list of GO command"
        go
  }

############################################################################
# Here is the check process, based on which the above function may be called.

$workDir = 'Documents\GoWorkPlace'
# Get latest Go lang version
# Parse the remote repository with ls-remote, and get release branches
# The regex matches refs/heads/release-branch.go, so rc and beta won't be mached
$release_branches=$(git ls-remote --heads https://github.com/golang/go/ | 
ConvertFrom-String | Where-Object {$_."P2" -Match 'refs/heads/release-branch.go'})

# Define utility for nat sort (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5429048/2796058)
$ToNatural = { [regex]::Replace($_, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft(20) }) }

# Extract actual tag versions, sort and get latest
$latest_version=$($release_branches.P2 | Select-String -Pattern '(\d+\.\d+)').Matches.Groups.Value |
 Sort-Object $ToNatural | Select-Object -Last 1

 Write-Output " Latest GO lang version is: $latest_version"

# Check installed version of GO lang 
$cmdName = 'go'
Try{
    Get-Command $cmdName -ErrorAction stop
    $goversioncheck = go version
    $goversion = [regex]::Match($goversioncheck, '((\d+\.\d+))').captures.groups[1].value

    if ($goversion -eq $latest_version) {
        Write-Output " You already have latest GO lang version installed, version: $goversion"
    } else {
        Write-Host " Upgrade Install of GO lang will start now"
        InstallGo -latest_version $latest_version -workDir $workDir
    }
  } Catch{
    Write-Host " Fresh Install of GO lang will start now"
    InstallGo -latest_version $latest_version -workDir $workDir
  }
```

Above to using portable/zip file, as it does not required admin privileges, if you prefer working with the `msi` file, then you need to replace the file name from `.windows-amd64.zip` to `.windows-amd64.msi` and replace file extraction command `Expand-Archive -Force -Path $dest -DestinationPath $path\..` by file execution command `Start-Process $dest`

Comment: @Paolo do not be depressed my friend, my intention was to document my understand of it, nothing else, your answer is deeply appreciated. Hope we are fine now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use to query GitHub's Tags API to fetch all the tags.

If you're using PowerShell 6 or newer, you can take advantage of `Invoke-RestMethod`'s `-FollowRelLink` parameter to consume multi-paged results:

```bsh
$tags = Invoke-RestMethod "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tags?per_page=100" -FollowRelLink
```

In Windows PowerShell you would need to handle parsing the links manually, perhaps something like:

```bsh
$response = Invoke-WebRequest "https://api.github.com/repos/golang/go/tags?per_page=100"

$tags = while($? -and $response.StatusCode -eq 200){
    # emit tag names from result page
    $response |ConvertFrom-Json

    # check if there's more data
    $nextPageLink = $response.Headers['Link'].Split(",").Where({$_ -like '*rel="next"'},'First')
    if(-not $nextPageLink){
        break
    }
    $nextPageLink = $nextPageLink.Split(";")[0].Trim(' <>')

    # continue fetching
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest $nextPageLink
}
```

In both cases, once we have the tag objects we just need to locate the latest relevant version:

```
$latestVersion = @($tags.Name) -match '^go[\.\d]+$' |Sort-Object -Descending |Select-Object -First 1
```

And then you can pass `$latestVersion` to your installer script.

Comment: The first line gave me error: `Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FollowRelLink'.`

Comment: The second option gave me latest version as `go1.9.7` while it is `go1.15`