# Sort an array numerically by extracting integers in names

Tags: arrays, powershell, sorting

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSScriptRoot | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
```

I get the output

```
Set 1
Set 10
Set 11 - A Memo
Set 2
Set 20
Set 22 - A Memo With Numbers 1234
Set 3
Set 33 - A Memo
...
```

$Folders = $Folders | Sort-Object {[INT]($_ -Replace 'Set ', '')} will sort the names in the right order but doesn't work if there is anything after the number like ' - A Memo'.

I've tried \b\d+\b on https://regexr.com but don't know how to implement that in this case.
I need a regex that can extract the number after 'Set ' and discard everything else.

RegEx is a whole other language in itself

Comment: If the desired order would be `1,2,3..10,11` instead of `1,10,11,2`... the question is about [natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does) sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some alternatives for extracting the number, complementing [g.sulman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039142/g-sulman)'s excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65876047/7571258).

First the most simplest method, assuming "Set" and the number are always separated by space:

```
$Folders | Sort-Object { [int]($_ -split ' ')[1] }
```

This uses the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7.1) operator to split the string on space character, which returns an array. Then it converts the 2nd element to `int`.

---

Use [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#matching-operators) operator:

```
$Folders | Sort-Object { [int]( $_ -match '\d+' ? $matches[0] : 0 ) }
```

Note that conditional operator `?` requires PS 7. Alternative for older PS versions:

```
$Folders | Sort-Object { [int]( if( $_ -match '\d+' ){ $matches[0] } else { 0 } ) }
```

The `-match` operator finds the first sub string that matches the RegEx `\d+` which stands for one or more digits. The found sub string can be accessed through `$matches[0]`.

---

Use `Select-String` cmdlet:

```
$Folders | Sort-Object { [int] ( $_ | Select-String -Pattern \d+ ).Matches[0].Value }
```

Same principle as the `-match` method. Just a different way to access the found sub string.

Comment: Thank you.  The split solution works great.  Don't know why it never occurred to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$names = @"
Set 1
Set 10
Set 11 - A Memo
Set 2
Set 20
Set 22 - A Memo With Numbers 1234
Set 3
Set 33 - A Memo
"@ -split "`n"

$names | sort @{expression={[int]($_ -replace '^\w+\s|\s.+')}}
```

You can use an expression with [**`Sort-Object`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/sorting-objects?view=powershell-5.1#using-hash-tables). Above this is done to replace everything you don't care about and convert to `int` for number sorting (in text sorting `1, 10, 11, 2, 20 ...` is expected.)

**Regex breakdown**

```
^  - start of the string
\w - word character (matches S)
+  - the previous thing as many times as need (matches Se, Set, Seet, Seeeeeeeet)
\s - space
|  - or. so either everything before this, or everything after
\s - space
.  - any character
+  - I think this one's covered above
```

Note: `+` matches 1 or more. Use `*` if you need to match 0 or more.

**Edit:** As per zett42's helpful comment, you could use `[int]($_ -split ' ')[1]` in the `Sort-Object` expression. This splits your name into an array, and takes the 2nd element of that array.