How can i select files using powershell?
I have files
Test1.zip
Test2.zip
Test3.zip
Test10.zip
Test11.zip

When i do a select in powershell using this command
  Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp" -Filter "*.zip" | Sort-Object

when i run the command it comes out
Test1.zip
Test10.zip
Test11.zip
Test2.zip
Test3.zip

How can i make it come out ?
Test1.zip
Test2.zip
Test3.zip
Test10.zip
Test11.zip

         


related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427506/how-to-sort-by-file-name-the-same-way-windows-explorer-does

Officially:
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\temp" -Filter "*.zip" | Sort-Object -Property {[Int]$_.BaseName.TrimStart('test')}

Quickly:
gci "c:\temp\*.zip" | Sort {[Int]$_.BaseName.Trim('test')}

Showing Only Name:
(gci "c:\temp\*.zip" | Sort {[Int]$_.BaseName.Trim('test')}).Name

The Output:
test1.zip
test2.zip
test3.zip
test10.zip
test11.zip


Even though the OP used "test" in all their example filenames, it's possible that they may have other filenames as well: red1, red10, red100, blue1, blue10, blue100.  Being locked into only one term "test", "red" or "blue" is not a very robust solution.

-@Daniel I answered based on the question. If you want more options than questions, it's better to create a new question.

That's not a good attitude to take when posting answers on this site, but I wish you the best.

-@Daniel Thank for suggestion. It's also not good to answer with a complex answer that is not in the question.

Given that the command in the question uses *.zip - not test*.zip - it is fair to assume that the uniform test prefix is incidental to the desired solution and was provided merely to simplify showing desired sample output. As written, your answer addresses an unhelpfully narrow use case, as Daniel has pointed out.

Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\temp" -Filter "*.zip" retrieves all files with a .zip extension in the specified directory.
Sort-Object is used with a custom sorting script block { ... } to sort the files based on a transformed key.
Within the script block:
[regex]::Replace($.Name, '\d+', { $args[0].Value.PadLeft($.Name.Length, '0') }) extracts numeric sequences from each file name using regex (\d+) and pads them with leading zeros up to the length of the file name ($_.Name.Length) to ensure numerical values are compared correctly.
This transformation ensures that Test10.zip comes after Test9.zip but before Test11.zip in the sorted list.

are you able to put it in a working example ?

What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?

Should you refrain from answering if you can't format an answer? "Yes, if you are unable to format your posts to ensure that they are readable, either because of unwillingness, incompetence, or technical limitations, then you should refrain from answering the question until you can address that problem."
