# Unable to get sub folders in sorted order

Tags: batch-file, cmd, directory, subdirectory

We have deployment cmd file in which we use 
`dir /s /od /b Current\*.sql`
it was working fine till 99.sql but when we introduce 100.sql the 100.sql runs before 99.sql how to correct the sort order ? 100.sql is created after 99.sql so /od should list 99.sql before 100.sql. 
So help me how to get right order.

[image]

Comment: Alot easier to copy and paste the text from the console window then posting a screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute easiest way is to zero-pad all the numbers, i.e. `61` becomes `0061`, but this'll require doing it to the old files as well.

Failing that, you can sort the files naturally; there seems to be an answer for that here. [Naturally Sort Files in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19297935/naturally-sort-files-in-batch)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /od /ad "current*"') do if exist "current\%%a\*.sql" dir /s /b /od "current\%%a\*.sql"
```

This should first scan `current` for directorynames (`/ad`) in date-order (`/od`) then look for files matching "current*namefound**.sql" and list if any exist.